# Print out data according to the Date and list them in sequential number

Tags: cakephp

I got some sample data in a Table Testing which consists of two fields:
(there is not primary key in this sample Table)

### Data | Date

Hello     |  2010-07-1 15:11:11
World   | 2010-07-1 11:01:01
Hi there  | 2010-07-02 11:36:11

I was trying to print the data out Ordered by Date DESC in this way:

Record 1: Hi there
Record 2: Hello
Record 3: World

I have no idea how to do this using either cakePHP or PHP.

Please help if you could.

Comment: Are you using CakePHP? If so you might want to add that as a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain PHP you can do this using [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

The SQL would be:

```
SELECT data FROM yourtable ORDER BY Date DESC
```

The manual for mysql_query includes an example showing how you can execute the SQL statement and iterate over the result set. If you're having problems, post your code and the specific error.